# 405 - HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed - IIS 7.5

Tags: iis-7.5, httpverbs

Good Day,

I am struggling with this error when I try to access one of my pages on my site. The error reads in full - `405 - HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed. The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid method (HTTP verb) was used to attempt access.` The website is an asp.net website compiled to run in a .NET 4.0 application pool.

The site has 1 handler specified in the web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>         
        <add verb="*" path="*adapter" name="AdapterHandler" type="AdapterHandler" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

I also see this handler on IIS.

[image: HandlerMapping]

All verbs are allowed! I have no idea why this suddenly occurs. Any Advice?

Comment: Forgot to mention, `WebDav` is not installed on my IIS

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the link to my page set up on a remote system pointed to the FOLDER in which the page resided in, not to the Page itself.

Comment: The joys of working with partners in foreign countries :)